# After auto upgrade to 5.8 seeing errors and site unusable

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

After an auto upgrade to 5.8 seeing this error... can't even run the wp-cli to downgrade back to 5.7.2. I forgot to turn off the auto upgrade to this one particular site...

> 2021/07/23 14:46:03 [error] 83504#0: *10332 FastCGI sent in stderr:
> "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class
> WP_Block_Template, because the name is already in use in
> /Library/WebServer/clients/test/FASLAND/wp-content/plugins/gutenberg/lib/full-site-editing/class-wp-block-template.php
> on line 12" while reading response header from upstream, client:
> 192.168.1.1, server: xx.xx.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host:
> "xx.xx.com" 2021/07/23 14:46:04 [error] 83504#0:
> *10334 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot declare class WP_Block_Template, because the name is already in use in
> /Library/WebServer/clients/test/FASLAND/wp-content/plugins/gutenberg/lib/full-site-editing/class-wp-block-template.php
> on line 12" while reading response header from upstream, client:
> 192.168.1.1, server: xx.xx.com, request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host:
> "xx.xx.com", referrer:
> "https://xx.xx.com/"

Answer (score 2):

The critical error is caused by the Gutenberg plugin attempting to redeclare the class `WP_Block_Template` which is now included as part of the WordPress Core as of version 5.8

Ref: [WordPress/wp-includes/class-wp-block-template.php](https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/4ae0e4220f0c01005afa0dcbb74979c0d5cb9abc/wp-includes/class-wp-block-template.php)

To resolve this issue, uninstall the Gutenberg plugin.
For WP-CLI, use the command:

```
wp plugin uninstall gutenberg
```

Comment: Optionally, if you still want to use the gutenberg plugin, after uninstalling the conflicting version of the plugin then install the latest version (updated 3 days ago, the same time WordPress 5.8 was released..)

Comment: Hey.. thanks all I was able to push the plugin aside and get it back up for now...thanks for this.